# How to send a contribution receipt through a text message when receiving a donation

Tags: civicontribute, civirules, sms

I would like to know if it is possible to send a text confirmation message or a WhatsApp when we receive a contribution from a donor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send text messages with CiviCRM. Look at [Setting up an SMS provider](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS)! 
But you want to send a message the moment you register a contribution. The extension [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) can do this task for you. It allows you to configure an action (for example sending a text message) that must be executed when a predefined event happens (for example, adding a contribution). See the [CiviRules Cookbook] (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Cookbook).